# Using c99 in C++'s `extern "C"` blocks

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, extern

I would like to have a function written in C, but callable from C++ which takes a restricted pointer. This is only available in c99, so g++ doesn't like it, even in `extern "C"` blocks. How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean that the contained code is C, it means that any functions or items declared there will use C linkage.

Comment: Just kidding: try `extern "C99"`

Comment: Similar issue here: `struct XY a = { .x = 1, .y = 2 };` does NOT compile inside an extern "C" block: _error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token_, so frustrating! Instead, obsolete form `struct XY a = { x: 1, y: 2 };` DOES work. Ouch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#   ifdef __GNUC__
#       define restrict __restrict__ // G++ has restrict
#   else
#       define restrict // C++ in general doesn't
#   endif
#endif
```